# Want to get and set text color using onClick

Tags: javascript, java, android

I need some help on how to change the color of a textView on each click of a button using Android Studio.

```js
        View.OnClickListener buttonOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                if (textView.getCurrentTextColor() == 0xff0000)
                    textView.setTextColor(0x800080);
                if (textView.getCurrentTextColor() == 0xff0000)
                    textView.setTextColor(0x800080);
            }
        };

        changeColor.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of hex codes or colors and pick a random one this way :

```
list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))
```

Add this instruction in the *onClick* handler.

You should not hardcode colors. Use *colors.xml* instead :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is you have the same if statement for both, so it would only ever change if the starting color was 0x800080.

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

View.OnClickListener buttonOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (textView.getCurrentTextColor() == 0xff0000)
                    textView.setTextColor(0x800080);
                if (textView.getCurrentTextColor() == 0x800080)
                    textView.setTextColor(0xff0000);
            }
        };

changeColor.setOnClickListener(buttonOnClickListener);
```

---

**Note**: I moved the textView assignment outside of the onClick. No need to call findViewById on every click as it's a costly operation :)